# How to save in *.xlsx long URL in cell using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

For example I read excel file into DataFrame with 2 columns(id and URL). URLs in input file are like text(without hyperlinks):

```
input_f = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")
```

Watch what inside this DataFrame - everything was successfully read, all URLs are ok in `input_f`. After that when I wan't to save this file to_excel

```
input_f.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

I got warning.

> **Path**\worksheet.py:836: UserWarning: Ignoring URL **'http:// here long URL'** with
>   link or location/anchor > 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's
>   limit for URLS   force_unicode(url))

And in output.xlsx cells with long URL were empty, and URLs become hyperlinks.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can create an ExcelWriter object with the option not to convert strings to urls:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(
    r'file.xlsx', 
    engine='xlsxwriter',
    options={'strings_to_urls': False}
)
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.close()
```

In more recent versions of Pandas, you need to write

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
   r'file.xlsx', 
   engine='xlsxwriter',
   engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}}
 )
```

Comment: fyi, for anyone else hitting this, xlsxwriter Release 1.2.3 increased max url length from 255 to 2079 characters, as supported in more recent versions of Excel, which might avoid need for `strings_to_urls=False`.

Comment: Is there a trick to get around the excel limit on the maximum number of URLs in a file? :)

Answer (score 5):

I tried it myself and got the same problem. You could try to create a temp csv file and then use xlsxwriter to create an excel file. Once done then delete the tmp file. xlsxwriter has a write_string method that will override the auto hyperlinking that excel does. This worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
inData = "C:/Users/martbar/Desktop/test.xlsx"
tmp = "C:/Users/martbar/Desktop/tmp.csv"
exFile = "C:/Users/martbar/Desktop/output.xlsx"

#read in data
df = pd.read_excel(inData)

#send to csv
df.to_csv(tmp, index=False)

#convert to excel
workbook = Workbook(exFile)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
with open(tmp, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            #if you use write instead of write_string you will get the error
            worksheet.write_string(r, c, col) 
workbook.close()

#delete tmp file
os.remove(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) in the section: "Passing XlsxWriter constructor options to Pandas", `'strings_to_urls': False` is now specified like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_example.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}})
```

and then keep doing what the accepted response suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492577/2375948):

```
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.close()
```