# (PYTHON) to_excel - Ignoring URL... 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to copy a dataframe into an Excel document:

```
dfPol.to_excel(writer, 'Influence on Policy', columns=colsPol)
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error as the URLs are too long:

```
Ignoring URL .... 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS
```

So, I found a solution which is to use:

```
dfPol.to_excel(writer, 'Influence on Policy', columns=colsPol, options={'strings_to_urls': False})
```

But I am getting an error of:

```
TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

As obviously options does not work with `to_excel`, which is what I am using for a lot of other code in my script (i.e. I want to stick with 'to_excel')

Are there any solutions to my problem?

This is not a duplicate of: [How to save in *.xlsx long URL in cell using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440528/how-to-save-in-xlsx-long-url-in-cell-using-pandas) as that is not about to_excel (it is about excelwriter)

Comment: Have you tried using strings_to_urls as a parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save in \*.xlsx long URL in cell using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440528/how-to-save-in-xlsx-long-url-in-cell-using-pandas)

Comment: options is an argument to a writer, not to a `to_excel` function

Comment: with a function? I am not sure how to even begin to do that for this particular task

Comment: Thank you  Mykola Shchetinin, so are you saying it is not possible with to_excel?

Comment: Please show the code where you create your `writer`

Comment: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/{}/Desktop/RF Data.xlsx'.format(staName2))

Comment: So, pass the `options={'strings_to_urls': False}` to the `pd.ExcelWriter` call

Comment: Perfect, thank you Mykola. If you want to give a formal answer, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @ScoutEU, posted it, thanks and good luck

Comment: It actually IS a duplicate question to that other link, because using an Excelwriter was not what the other question was about, but the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass the argument `options={'strings_to_urls': False}` to the `pd.ExcelWriter` call when creating your `writer`.
It will look something like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/{}/Desktop/RF Data.xlsx'.format(staName2),options={'strings_to_urls': False})
dfPol.to_excel(writer, 'Influence on Policy', columns=colsPol)
```

Comment: The code above didn't work for me until I included `writer.close()`.

Answer (score 5):

you can just use:

```
 with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, options={'strings_to_urls': False}) as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Influence on Policy', columns=colsPol)
```

Then you don't have to worry about closing your writer file

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the options={'strings_to_urls': False} parameter doesn't directly apply to the ExcelWriter initialization in Pandas and might throw a TypeError. To resolve this, a potential workaround involves passing the engine_kwargs parameter within the ExcelWriter context manager.

If you're encountering the TypeError and need to disable strings_to_urls, consider using this alternative approach:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(str(file.replace('.xlsx','_format.xlsx')),engine_kwargs={'options':{'strings_to_urls': False}}) as writer:
     data.to_excel(writer,index=False)
```